# way to dynamically allocate memory for CGPoint in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm a newbie in Objective-C, and I want to dynamically allocate memory for CGPoint in Objective-C like the vector template in C++. and be able to change the value in the array. I know NSMtubleArray can accomplish this, but would it be too tedious every time you wrap CGPoint into NSValue and then store NSValue into NSMtubleArray? and I encounter a runtime error using [NSMtubleArray replaceObjectWith:[NSValue vauleWithCGPoint:]].

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: What error do you get when you try to replace the object? Could you paste a snippet of the code where you are doing so?

Comment: you can use `std::vector<CGPoint>` with Objective-C++ (`.mm` extension)

Comment: Personally I don't like to use C++ classes in ObjC,I would go for another solution, and if I don't have any other way I prefer to wrap the C++ class in an ObjC one. But of course is matter of taste.

Comment: @xlc I'm afraid bringing up C++ for the task could result in over-engineering it

Answer (score 3):

If you find tedious to box and unbox CGPoint into NSValue and you need to access to the CGPoint fields directly at any time(otherwise it's not worth since you are not gaining anything comparing to `NSValue`'s methods `valueWithCGPoint:` and `CGPointValue`) you can create a class representing a point with some methods to convert to and from CGPoint with ease.

Something like this:

```
@interface MyPoint : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat x;

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat y;

- (id)initWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point;

+ (instancetype) pointWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point;

- (CGPoint) CGPoint;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation MyPoint

- (id)initWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _x = point.x;
        _y = point.y;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype) pointWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithCGPoint:point];
}

- (CGPoint) CGPoint
{
    return CGPointMake(_x, _y);
}

@end
```

Comment: if I use NSValue, how do I change the CGPoint it wrapped?

Comment: You cannot, NSValue is a inmutable class.

Comment: With `NSValue` you can only retrieve the wrapped value and create a new `NSValue` with the modified point. `CGPoint yourPoint = [yourValue CGPointValue]; yourPoint.x = 42; NSValue * aNewValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:yourPoint];`

Comment: Thanks, actually I don't even need CGPoint, the reason I use it is to represent 2d vector.

Comment: @e1985 what is this method "+(instancetype) pointWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)" used for? I have to use this method to instantiate the class(I mean create a new object)?

Comment: It is just a class factory method to avoid calling alloc/initWithCGPoint:. If you have any doubt about instancetype check this article: http://nshipster.com/instancetype/

Comment: @e1985 thank you. Now I plan to implement a class representing 2d vector. and I need to create some helper functions like normalize, dotproduct and length. Where should I put these functions? declare them as class level methods? As for functions like "normalize", I need to return a pointer to a new object, do I? what should I do in this case.

Comment: This kills all the pros of a struct.

Comment: I think those methods can be instance methods of your new class representing the 2d vector. Or maybe you could create a helper class with those methods receiving normal NSArrays and then returning new ones, it's matter of design and probably there are pro and cons for each option. I think I would go for the first option but more details are needed for this and that's a different topic :)

Comment: @Sulthan what would you suggest? create a struct?